# firebase-admin-sdk-go FCM messaging thread safety

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I've been trying to determine if the FCM messaging portion of the firebase-admin-sdk for Go is thread safe. I'm using `v4` of the sdk.

```
    firebase "firebase.google.com/go/v4"
    "firebase.google.com/go/v4/messaging"
```

I've found some other folks reporting that the auth portion of the SDK is thread safe. Based on that I would assume that means that messaging is as well but hoping to get some confirmation since I don't see it called out in the documentation.

My use case is I'm essentially creating one instance of the the FCM messaging client in an api service. There could be any number of parallel uses of this client calling the `fcmClient.Send()` method at any one time after it has been initialized.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe to be called from multiple concurrent routines. The only shared resource is the underlying `http.Client` instance, which is thread safe: https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go

I'm assuming each of your routines construct their own `messaging.Message` struct. If multiple routines share and modify the same `Message`, you're likely to encounter issues like the lost update problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm building each message using the literal approach like `&messaging.MulticastMessage{}` so I should be ok